# Is there a mobile app for viewing stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I was looking and kept finding posts on android.stackexchange.com but nothing for what I wanted. Does anyone know if there's a way to natively view the stack exchange interface on a phone?

Answer (score 4):

Here 
https://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone

Comment: Thank you! this site is sexy

Answer (score 1):

It actually looks pretty good on my samsung captivate. I was thinking I might enjoy working on an app to view stackexchange.

Comment: Yeah, could be a good project!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but there are plenty of RSS readers for mobiles. So you can at least subscribe to the feeds and get notifications on the move...

Comment: I was thinking about that, it just seems so well suited to be a native app though. I figured the StackOverflow guys would have jumped on something like that but I understand everything takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the site works fine on my HTC Hero, in the native Android (2.1) browser. The only parts which don't quite work are trying  to add a link to a reply (using the buttons above the textarea) and dismissing the notification messages (ie when you gain a badge). Otherwise I could almost believe that StackExchange sites were designed to be viewed on an Android phone.

Comment: yeah, i agree. I was just thinking their might be a way your could design the site for someone with a touch phone and make an app to handle that.

Comment: I seem to remember seeing an Android app in its' early stages last year (it was.for use  with the original SOFU sites). But it only let you look at posts, you couldn't vote, comment, post or ask a new question so it looked fairly useless to me.