# ios app for stackexchange

Tags: discussion

in the link (https://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone) provided in one of answers of the question :[Is there a mobile app for viewing stack exchange?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/is-there-a-mobile-app-for-viewing-stack-exchange) , I if found out that there is a stackexchange app for android, but there was none for ios.
Is there any stackexchange app for the ios anyway?

Comment: This question might receive better attention on the [main Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), rather than the Electronics StackExchange meta.

Comment: sure sir, will post one there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer to my question here:https://stackapps.com/questions/2115/fullstack-ipad-app
It was found in the main Meta site